Magento 2.4.7: CSP Errors with Inline script on the Checkout page
This is a follow up to this question: Magento 2.4.7 - Advice setting up csp
I have set-up/configured a custom csp module. This is the current csp_whitelist.xml:
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<csp_whitelist xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Csp:etc/csp_whitelist.xsd">
    <policies>
        <policy id="default-src">
            <values>
                <value id="data" type="host">'self'</value>
            </values>
        </policy>
        <policy id="base-uri">
            <values>
                <value id="data" type="host">'self'</value>
            </values>
        </policy>
        <policy id="font-src">
            <values>
                <value id="data" type="host">'self' data: https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com</value>
                <value id="bootstrapcdn" type="host">*.bootstrapcdn.com</value>
                <value id="fontawesome" type="host">*.fontawesome.com</value>
                <value id="googleapis" type="host">*.googleapis.com</value>
                <value id="gstatic" type="host">*.gstatic.com</value>
            </values>
        </policy>
        <policy id="style-src">
            <values>
                <value id="hash" type="hash" algorithm="sha256">W5akSSK6LD5BjIlNICMcXaUObQSRAaj6bs7JHADURBA=</value>
                <value id="hash2" type="hash" algorithm="sha256">3qVqeAdyxxTdPkkRzqapjGkAUYLahxSrB7Mdup+GPQ0=</value>
                <value id="hash3" type="hash" algorithm="sha256">2rvfFrggTCtyF5WOiTri1gDS8Boibj4Njn0e+VCBmDI=</value>
                <value id="hash4" type="hash" algorithm="sha256">p8MCfMHqrovsjRYU9z0bU17dd0z81k/fVbGrtBBiM9g=</value>
                <value id="hash5" type="hash" algorithm="sha256">0pk2s4oXwBELlC6IBVb3nNaM2PjfjwI2N6OGIX5lx8Y=</value>
                <value id="hash6" type="hash" algorithm="sha256">nkEZknO0IxNxY/CkTMBhjNhwPvglpYumjx31B4fjkY8=</value>
                <value id="data" type="host">'report-sample'</value>
                <value id="data2" type="host">'self'</value>
                <value id="data3" type="host">'unsafe-inline'</value>
                <value id="data4" type="host">https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com</value>
                <value id="bootstrapcdn" type="host">*.bootstrapcdn.com</value>
                <value id="cloudflare" type="host">*.cloudflare.com</value>
                <value id="fontawesome" type="host">*.fontawesome.com</value>
                <value id="google-apis" type="host">*.googleapis.com</value>
                <value id="gstatic" type="host">*.gstatic.com</value>
            </values>
        </policy>
        <policy id="img-src">
            <values>
                <value id="data" type="host">'self'</value>
                <value id="adobedtm-assets" type="host">assets.adobedtm.com</value>
                <value id="adobedtm-all" type="host">*.adobedtm.com</value>
                <value id="cloudflare" type="host">*.cloudflare.com</value>
                <value id="googleadservices" type="host">*.googleadservices.com</value>
                <value id="google-analytics" type="host">*.google-analytics.com</value>
                <value id="vimeocdn" type="host">*.vimeocdn.com</value>
            </values>
        </policy>
        <policy id="connect-src">
            <values>
                <value id="data" type="host">'self'</value>
                <value id="cloudflare" type="host">*.cloudflare.com</value>
                <value id="google-maps" type="host">'self' https://maps.googleapis.com</value>
            </values>
        </policy>
        <policy id="frame-src">
            <values>
                <value id="data" type="host">'self'</value>
                <value id="stripe" type="host">https://js.stripe.com</value>
                <value id="google" type="host">*.google.com</value>
            </values>
        </policy>
        <policy id="script-src">
            <values>
                <value id="hash" type="hash" algorithm="sha256">W5akSSK6LD5BjIlNICMcXaUObQSRAaj6bs7JHADURBA=</value>
                <value id="hash2" type="hash" algorithm="sha256">3qVqeAdyxxTdPkkRzqapjGkAUYLahxSrB7Mdup+GPQ0=</value>
                <value id="hash3" type="hash" algorithm="sha256">2rvfFrggTCtyF5WOiTri1gDS8Boibj4Njn0e+VCBmDI=</value>
                <value id="hash4" type="hash" algorithm="sha256">p8MCfMHqrovsjRYU9z0bU17dd0z81k/fVbGrtBBiM9g=</value>
                <value id="hash5" type="hash" algorithm="sha256">0pk2s4oXwBELlC6IBVb3nNaM2PjfjwI2N6OGIX5lx8Y=</value>
                <value id="hash6" type="hash" algorithm="sha256">nkEZknO0IxNxY/CkTMBhjNhwPvglpYumjx31B4fjkY8=</value>
                <value id="report-sample" type="host">'report-sample'</value>
                <value id="self" type="host">'self'</value>
                <value id="unsafe-eval" type="host">'unsafe-eval'</value>
                <value id="unsafe-hashes" type="host">'unsafe-hashes'</value>
                <value id="unsafe-inline" type="host">'unsafe-inline'</value>
                <value id="adobedtm-assets" type="host">assets.adobedtm.com</value>
                <value id="adobedtm-all" type="host">*.adobedtm.com</value>
                <value id="adobe" type="host">*.adobe.com</value>
                <value id="avada" type="host">*.avada.io</value>
                <value id="amcglobal" type="host">amcglobal.sc.omtrdc.net</value>
                <value id="braintree-api" type="host">api.braintreegateway.com</value>
                <value id="braintree-sandbox" type="host">api.sandbox.braintreegateway.com</value>
                <value id="braintree-analytics" type="host">client-analytics.braintreegateway.com</value>
                <value id="braintree-analytics-sand" type="host">client-analytics.sandbox.braintreegateway.com</value>
                <value id="braintree-js" type="host">js.braintreegateway.com</value>
                <value id="braintree-assets" type="host">assets.braintreegateway.com</value>
                <value id="cardinalcommerce" type="host">geostag.cardinalcommerce.com</value>
                <value id="cardinalcommerce2" type="host">1eafstag.cardinalcommerce.com</value>
                <value id="cardinalcommerce3" type="host">geoapi.cardinalcommerce.com</value>
                <value id="cardinalcommerce4" type="host">1eafapi.cardinalcommerce.com</value>
                <value id="cardinalcommerce5" type="host">songbird.cardinalcommerce.com</value>
                <value id="cardinalcommerce6" type="host">*.cardinalcommerce.com</value>
                <value id="cardinalcommerce7" type="host">songbirdstag.cardinalcommerce.com</value>
                <value id="commerce-payment8" type="host">*.commerce-payment-services.com</value>
                <value id="cloudflare" type="host">*.cloudflare.com</value>
                <value id="google-pay" type="host">pay.google.com</value>
                <value id="google-analytics" type="host">*.google-analytics.com</value>
                <value id="google-analytics2" type="host">www.google-analytics.com</value>
                <value id="google-analytics3" type="host">analytics.google.com</value>
                <value id="google-analytics4" type="host">analytics.google.com</value>
                <value id="googletagmanager" type="host">googletagmanager.com</value>
                <value id="googletagmanager2" type="host">www.googletagmanager.com</value>
                <value id="googletagmanager3" type="host">*.googletagmanager.com</value>
                <value id="google-apis" type="host">apis.google.com</value>
                <value id="google-apis2" type="host">*.googleapis.com</value>
                <value id="google-apis3" type="host">www.googleapis.com</value>
                <value id="google-ads" type="host">www.googleadservices.com</value>
                <value id="google-ads2" type="host">googleads.g.doubleclick.net</value>
                <value id="google-ads3" type="host">*.googleadservices.com</value>
                <value id="google-ads4" type="host">googleads.g.doubleclick.net</value>
                <value id="gstatic" type="host">*.gstatic.com</value>
                <value id="google-recaptcha" type="host">https://www.gstatic.com/recaptcha/</value>
                <value id="google-recaptcha2" type="host">https://www.google.com/recaptcha/</value>
                <value id="google-recaptcha3" type="host">www.google.com/recaptcha/</value>
                <value id="google-recaptcha4" type="host">www.gstatic.com/recaptcha/</value>
                <value id="google-recaptcha5" type="host">https://www.gstatic.com/recaptcha</value>
                <value id="google-recaptcha6" type="host">https://www.google.com/recaptcha</value>
                <value id="google" type="host">google.com</value>
                <value id="google2" type="host">*.google.com</value>
                <value id="google3" type="host">*.google.com/</value>
                <value id="google-maps" type="host">https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js</value>
                <value id="includestest" type="host">includestest.ccdc02.com</value>
                <value id="instagram" type="host">*.instagram.com</value>
                <value id="klarna" type="host">klarna.com</value>
                <value id="klarna2" type="host">*.klarna.com</value>
                <value id="klarna3" type="host">*.klarnacdn.net</value>
                <value id="klarna4" type="host">*.klarnaevt.com</value>
                <value id="magento-ds" type="host">*.magento-ds.com</value>
                <value id="newrelic" type="host">*.newrelic.com</value>
                <value id="nr-data" type="host">*.nr-data.net</value>
                <value id="paypal" type="host">www.paypal.com</value>
                <value id="paypal-objects" type="host">www.paypalobjects.com</value>
                <value id="paypal-objects2" type="host">*.paypalobjects.com</value>
                <value id="paypal-t" type="host">t.paypal.com</value>
                <value id="paypal-c" type="host">c.paypal.com</value>
                <value id="paypal-all" type="host">*.paypal.com</value>
                <value id="paypal-sandbox" type="host">www.sandbox.paypal.com</value>
                <value id="paypal-sandbox2" type="host">sandbox.paypal.com</value>
                <value id="paypal-sandbox3" type="host">*.sandbox.paypal.com</value>
                <value id="paypal-t2" type="host">t.paypal.com</value>
                <value id="stripe-js" type="host">https://js.stripe.com/v3/</value>
                <value id="stripe-all" type="host">*.stripe.com</value>
                <value id="stripe-link" type="host">*.link.com</value>
                <value id="typekit" type="host">*.typekit.net</value>
                <value id="typekit2" type="host">use.typekit.net</value>
                <value id="vimeo" type="host">*.vimeo.com</value>
                <value id="vimeo2" type="host">www.vimeo.com</value>
                <value id="vimeo3" type="host">*.vimeocdn.com</value>
                <value id="youtube" type="host">*.youtube.com</value>
                <value id="ytimg" type="host">s.ytimg.com</value>
            </values>
        </policy>
        <policy id="media-src">
            <values>
                <value id="data" type="host">'self'</value>
            </values>
        </policy>
        <policy id="manifest-src">
            <values>
                <value id="data" type="host">'self'</value>
            </values>
        </policy>
        <policy id="object-src">
            <values>
                <value id="data" type="host">'none'</value>
                <value id="hash" type="hash" algorithm="sha256">W5akSSK6LD5BjIlNICMcXaUObQSRAaj6bs7JHADURBA=</value>
                <value id="hash2" type="hash" algorithm="sha256">3qVqeAdyxxTdPkkRzqapjGkAUYLahxSrB7Mdup+GPQ0=</value>
                <value id="hash3" type="hash" algorithm="sha256">2rvfFrggTCtyF5WOiTri1gDS8Boibj4Njn0e+VCBmDI=</value>
                <value id="hash4" type="hash" algorithm="sha256">p8MCfMHqrovsjRYU9z0bU17dd0z81k/fVbGrtBBiM9g=</value>
                <value id="hash5" type="hash" algorithm="sha256">0pk2s4oXwBELlC6IBVb3nNaM2PjfjwI2N6OGIX5lx8Y=</value>
                <value id="hash6" type="hash" algorithm="sha256">nkEZknO0IxNxY/CkTMBhjNhwPvglpYumjx31B4fjkY8=</value>
            </values>
        </policy>
        <policy id="worker-src">
            <values>
                <value id="data" type="host">'none'</value>
            </values>
        </policy>
    </policies>
</csp_whitelist>

I need assistance with stopping the following console errors (I have another 8 similar):

Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following
Content Security Policy directive: "script-src assets.adobedtm.com
*.adobe.com   googleads.g.doubleclick.net analytics.google.com  *.newrelic.com *.nr-data.net
geostag.cardinalcommerce.com 1eafstag.cardinalcommerce.com
geoapi.cardinalcommerce.com 1eafapi.cardinalcommerce.com
songbird.cardinalcommerce.com includestest.ccdc02.com  
 t.paypal.com s.ytimg.com  *.vimeo.com  *.vimeocdn.com
*.youtube.com   *.commerce-payment-services.com *.typekit.net google.com *.google.com amcglobal.sc.omtrdc.net *.magento-ds.com use.typekit.net js.braintreegateway.com assets.braintreegateway.com c.paypal.com pay.google.com
api.braintreegateway.com api.sandbox.braintreegateway.com
client-analytics.braintreegateway.com
client-analytics.sandbox.braintreegateway.com *.paypal.com
songbirdstag.cardinalcommerce.com *.googleapis.com *.gstatic.com
*.instagram.com   'report-sample' 'self' 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-hashes' 'unsafe-inline' *.adobedtm.com *.avada.io
*.cardinalcommerce.com *.cloudflare.com *.google-analytics.com googletagmanager.com *.googletagmanager.com apis.google.com
*.googleadservices.com   *.google.com/  klarna.com *.klarna.com *.klarnacdn.net *.klarnaevt.com *.paypalobjects.com sandbox.paypal.com *.sandbox.paypal.com  *.stripe.com *.link.com
'self' 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-hashes'
'nonce-b243ZGoxZTNxcW83MHFsZzY3dGgxcnNmOXlweGtnY2Q='
'sha256-W5akSSK6LD5BjIlNICMcXaUObQSRAaj6bs7JHADURBA='
'sha256-3qVqeAdyxxTdPkkRzqapjGkAUYLahxSrB7Mdup+GPQ0='
'sha256-2rvfFrggTCtyF5WOiTri1gDS8Boibj4Njn0e+VCBmDI='
'sha256-p8MCfMHqrovsjRYU9z0bU17dd0z81k/fVbGrtBBiM9g='
'sha256-0pk2s4oXwBELlC6IBVb3nNaM2PjfjwI2N6OGIX5lx8Y='
'sha256-nkEZknO0IxNxY/CkTMBhjNhwPvglpYumjx31B4fjkY8='
local.adguard.org 'nonce-5f7358088e0046b0b925f4cfd5b'". Note that
'unsafe-inline' is ignored if either a hash or nonce value is present
in the source list.

I have added the sha256 values to the whitelist but this has not stopped the console errors. What am I doing wrong please?

You want to disable CSP in latest version?

I've faced the same problem after the latest Magento 2.4.5-p8, 2.4.6-p6 and 2.4.7-p1 upgrade.
Disabling the CSP module is not a solution here as it has dependencies over other modules.
To fix this issue, you need to create the config.xml file under the below path.
app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/config.xml

And add the below content to it.
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Store:etc/config.xsd">
    <default>
        <csp>
            <policies>
                <storefront_checkout_index_index>
                    <scripts>
                        <inline>1</inline>
                    </scripts>
                </storefront_checkout_index_index>
            </policies>
        </csp>
    </default>
</config>

Flush the Magento cache (cache:flush) if you're adding this in the current module or run setup:upgrade in case you've created a new module. After that, the CSP errors are gone from the checkout page.
Hope it helps!!!

That's done it! Many thanks, no console errors now!

Is this really safe to enable all inline scripts rather than adding nonce or hashes?

This is not safe and not at all recommended.

okay @VineetSajwan, then please share what is recommended and safe to use as the Hash method is not working as Magento suggested.

@sumit I am also looking for a solution. However, enabling an inline script is not a solution.

This is not the right solution

Yes, I know, but I need to run the checkout process of my website. You're welcome to post the right solution here.

Probably those scripts are dynamic, there is some part of the script that changes on every page load. You can check that by comparing the page source of the same url after refreshing on your browser.

The following solution worked for me

Securely render the inline script
<?= $secureRenderer->renderTag('script', ['type' => 'text/javascript'], "\nconsole.log('I am a whitelisted script');\n", false); ?>
Hashing content of the inline script using base64_encode(hash('sha256', $content, true))
Add hash in the CSP policy
<?xml version="1.0"?> <csp_whitelist xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Csp:etc/csp_whitelist.xsd"> <policies> <policy id="script-src"> <values> <value id="my-scripts-hash" type="hash" algorithm="sha256">B4yPHKaXnvFWtRChIbabYmUBFZdVfKKXHbWtWidDVF8=</value> </values> </policy> </policies> </csp_whitelist>


Thanks for sharing this, Vineet, I'll try it out and confirm if it works for me.

On the console, check for the script where the error occurs and fix the inline script there. i.e if there is any  tag included within the phtml, change it to use the secureHtmlRenderer https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/php/development/security/content-security-policies/#whitelist-an-inline-script-or-style
